# How can I solve the following system using Python?

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I don't know how to solve the following system and then extract the values v_1, v_2, v_3 and v_n for the calculations in the prints.

```
import cmath
import math
import numpy as np

r3 = math.sqrt(3)
pp = cmath.exp(-1j * math.pi * 2 / 3)
U = 400
U_ph = U / r3
U_a = U_ph
U_b = U_a * pp
U_c = U_b * pp

S_HP = 3e3 - cmath.sqrt((3e3 / 0.95) ** 2 - 3e3 ** 2) * 1j
S_PV = -3.6e3 + 0j
S_EV = 16 * 400 * r3 + 0j

Z = 0.3 + 0.1j
Z_HP = (U_ph**2 / S_HP).conjugate()
Z_PV = (U_ph**2 / S_PV).conjugate()
Z_EV = (U_ph**2 / S_EV).conjugate()

v_1 = ((U_a/Z) + (v_n/Z_HP)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_HP))
v_2 = ((U_b/Z) + (v_n/Z_PV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_PV))
v_3 = ((U_c/Z) + (v_n/Z_EV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_EV))
v_n = ((v_1/Z_HP) + (v_2/Z_PV) + (v_3/Z_EV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_HP) + (1/Z_PV) + (1/Z_EV))

print(f"\n |v1-vn| = {np.abs(v_1 - v_n):.0f} V.")
print(f"\n |v2-vn| = {np.abs(v_2 - v_n):.0f} V.")
print(f"\n |v3-vn| = {np.abs(v_3 - v_n):.0f} V.")
```

I tried using sympy's symbols to solve the problem but I can't manage to extract the values of v_1, v_2, v_3 and v_n in the form of int or float values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share the sympy code you tried. Also, please share more details about the equations. Are each of the equations equal to 0?

Comment: How are you even accessing the value of `v_n` while computing `v_1` without setting it before?

Answer (score 1):

Use [sympy.solve](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-system-of-equations-algebraically.html) to solve a system of equations:

```
import cmath
import math
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

r3 = math.sqrt(3)
pp = cmath.exp(-1j * math.pi * 2 / 3)
U = 400
U_ph = U / r3
U_a = U_ph
U_b = U_a * pp
U_c = U_b * pp

S_HP = 3e3 - cmath.sqrt((3e3 / 0.95) ** 2 - 3e3 ** 2) * 1j
S_PV = -3.6e3 + 0j
S_EV = 16 * 400 * r3 + 0j

Z = 0.3 + 0.1j
Z_HP = (U_ph ** 2 / S_HP).conjugate()
Z_PV = (U_ph ** 2 / S_PV).conjugate()
Z_EV = (U_ph ** 2 / S_EV).conjugate()

v_1, v_2, v_3, v_n = sp.symbols("v_1 v_2 v_3 v_n")

solution = sp.solve([
    v_1 - ((U_a/Z) + (v_n/Z_HP)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_HP)),
    v_2 - ((U_b/Z) + (v_n/Z_PV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_PV)),
    v_3 - ((U_c/Z) + (v_n/Z_EV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_EV)),
    v_n - ((v_1/Z_HP) + (v_2/Z_PV) + (v_3/Z_EV)) / ((1/Z) + (1/Z_HP) + (1/Z_PV) + (1/Z_EV))
         ],
         [v_1, v_2, v_3, v_n]
)

v_1_val, v_2_val, v_3_val, v_n_val = solution[v_1], solution[v_2], solution[v_3], solution[v_n]

print(f"\n |v1-vn| = {np.abs(v_1_val - v_n_val):.0f} V.")
print(f"\n |v2-vn| = {np.abs(v_2_val - v_n_val):.0f} V.")
print(f"\n |v3-vn| = {np.abs(v_3_val - v_n_val):.0f} V.")
```

Comment: When using sympy one should stick to sympy functions, i.e. the cmath and math function calls should be replaced by sympy function calls.

Comment: True, although that is more important when the exact value of a sympy variable is required - here I don't think it is

Comment: I don't see why it would be a bad idea to just stick to one library. It would also reduce the code's dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right. It just wasn't absolutely necessary here so I only changed  the bare minimum from the OP's code - but it would be better to convert everything to sympy as you say.